# How can I use a numeric enum as an index in a type annotation?

Tags: typescript

I want to use a numeric enum as the index type in an object.

```
enum Weekday {
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday = 5,
    Sunday = 6
};

const isWeekend: { [day: Weekday]: boolean } = {
    [Weekday.Monday]: false,
    [Weekday.Tuesday]: false,
    [Weekday.Wednesday]: false,
    [Weekday.Thursday]: false,
    [Weekday.Friday]: false,
    [Weekday.Saturday]: true,
    [Weekday.Sunday]: true,
};
```

This code fails typechecking with the message:

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

I know of a couple workarounds. If I change `isWeekend`'s type to `{ [day: number]: boolean }` it will compile, but the type loses some precision.

How can I give `isWeekend` a more precise type without changing the definition of `Weekday`?

Comment: It looks like this proposal was [rejected](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2491), [accidentally fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2491#issuecomment-260431619), [accidentally broken](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13042), and finally [fixed again](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592) last year

Comment: Thanks, reading through those led me to my error: I was using `: Weekday` instead of `in Weekday`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this myself. I should have been using `day in Weekday` instead of `day: Weekday`. The following code works:

```
enum Weekday {
    Monday = 0,
    Tuesday = 1,
    Wednesday = 2,
    Thursday = 3,
    Friday = 4,
    Saturday = 5,
    Sunday = 6
};

const isWeekend: { [day in Weekday]: boolean } = {
    [Weekday.Monday]: false,
    [Weekday.Tuesday]: false,
    [Weekday.Wednesday]: false,
    [Weekday.Thursday]: false,
    [Weekday.Friday]: false,
    [Weekday.Saturday]: true,
    [Weekday.Sunday]: true,
};
```